# kubernetes Nodeport service : can't access with cluster ip

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy, weave

[1 Master : 10.166.232.164
2 Worker : 10.166.232.165, 10.166.232.166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOtjT.png)

[Deploy 3 replica pods for 2 worker nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWqHJ.png)

[Nodeport service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORX0j.png)

problem is i can access by curl podIP:8080

but

exec pod and access by clusterIP:Nodeport is not working

kubectl exec -it network-example2-84c98c7b4d-d7wnr /bin/bash -- curl 10.98.10.159:8080
=> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.98.10.159 port 8080: Connection refused

kubectl exec -it network-example2-84c98c7b4d-d7wnr /bin/bash -- curl 10.98.10.159:23060
=> no answer(maybe timeout error)

is it firewall problem..? or CNI..?

I'm using weave-net and no change any config

Comment: tried `localhost` inside container?

Answer (score 1):

A closer look to your screenshot indicate you have set `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local`. Try:

`curl 10.166.232.165:32060 or curl 10.166.232.166:32060`

"Local" means only the node which has the pod running will response to you, otherwise your request will be drop. Change to "Cluster" if you wish all the nodes will response to you regardless if it has the pod running.

Comment: master node IP: 10.166.232.164
worker node IP : 10.166.232.165,  10.166.232.166

Nodeport : 32060

and curl 10.166.232.165:32060  
=>
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.166.232.165 port 32060: Connection refused

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.

Comment: delete service, deployment and  re apply that, then External Traffic Policy turns to be 'cluster' but still no reply with "kubectl exec -it network-example2-84c98c7b4d-d7wnr /bin/bash -- curl 10.109.161.92:32060"

Comment: `10.109.161.92` - this is not a node IP. You should curl **10.166.232.165**:32060 or **10.166.232.166**:32060

Comment: it still has error,   
curl : (7) Failed to connect to 10.166.232.165:32060 : Connection refused

is it related to "kube-proxy"  logs like can't open port, skipping it err=listen tcp4 : 32060 bind : address already in use

Comment: Checkout the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707316/14704799) in your other question.