# kube proxy log can't open service Nodeport

Tags: kubernetes

service type : Nodeport

problem : can't access clusterIP:Nodeport

and find kube-proxy pod log like below

"can't open port, skipping it" err="listen tcp4 :32060: bind: address already in use" port={Description:nodePort for default/network-example2 IP: IPFamily:4 Port:32060 Protocol:TCP}

what is the problem??

Comment: with Node port you have to use the Node IP, `NodeIP:Nodeport`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by a reported [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107170) in the kube-proxy versions after v1.20.x (mine is v1.23.4). This [fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/107413) is merged in the upcoming v1.24 release.

It is also confirmed in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107297) that there would be no error if downgraded to the earlier release v1.20.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the process on the node that is using the port is kube-proxy itself. If this is the case, you could have hit a potential known issue of kube-proxy reported [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107297).

Comment: i don't allocate specific Nodeport in service spec.
it is allocated automatically...

Comment: Checkout the updated answer.